# Magento Layered Navigation on Subcategories not shown

Tags: magento, filter, navigation

On my store I can see the layered navigation on the top level categories pages, but not on sub-categories.
How I can show the filters on the sub-categories pages?
Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably you did not defined the subcategories as "Anchor". To do this, go to Catalog - Manage Categories. Click on a subcategory, go to Display Settings and set "Is Anchor" to "Yes".

Comment: Your answer saved my time, Great Thanks - @simon

Comment: @simon: i have set "Is Anchor" to "Yes" but subcategory is not showing.

there are total  5 subcategories in which 4 are showing and 1 is not showing.

Comment: @Trliok the question is about filters, not about the display of subcategories. Seems to be another issue - so open another question. The subcategories may simply be disabled/inactive.

Comment: @simon : yes this is for filter but in layred navigation 1 category is missing.

Comment: @Trliok then maybe there is no product assigned to this category or indexes or... Open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Beside checking:

```
Edit Category -> Display Settings -> Is Anchor
```

Also check:

```
Edit Category -> Design -> Layout Update XML
```

If the `Layout Update XML` field has the following code then the `layered navigation` will not be displayed in the particular category that you are editing:

```
<referenceContainer name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true"/>
```